# Create multiple array depending on a variable

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to create in Python multiple arrays whose names depend on a variable j, like this:

```
for j in range(30):
    x_j = np.loadtxt(f'Fid{j}.txt','r', unpack = True)
```

and the result would be to create 30 arrays x0, x1 .... x29. (Of course this code won't work).

I cannot make a matrix because each of this txt files has a different length, and I don't want to fill them with zeros because it would change a lot.

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Probably but I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary where the key is `j` and value is the array itself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you to ask yourself, why you would want to create 30 independent variables for 30 different arrays in the first place?

Creating a dictionary with `j` as the key variable probably is the better way.

E.g.

```
x = dict()
for j in range(30):
   x[j] = np.loadtxt(f'Fid{j}.txt','r', unpack = True)
```

You can then acess each of these arrays easily by the "variables" `x[0]`,
`x[17]`, or `x[29]` wherever you need to access them later in your code.